# Edit RAW column in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 18.3 but when I want to edit(or insert) a column with RAW datatype it shows the field as read only and does not allow to edit.

As you may know Oracle SQL Developer shows RAW datatype as hex string despite BLOB datatype that it does not show the value but you can download and upload the BLOB data.

I know that I can update(or insert) the RAW data as hex string like this :

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1(the_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, raw_col RAW(2000));

INSERT INTO t1(the_id, raw_col) VALUES(1, '1a234c');
```

But I want do it by Oracle SQL Developer GUI.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, and it doesn't *really* matter here, but your insert is doing an [implicit conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-98BE3A78-6E33-4181-B5CB-D96FD9DC1694); you can avoid that with [VALUES(1, HEXTORAW('1a234c'))`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/HEXTORAW.html). The end result is the same *8-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, we do not have a 'raw' editor like we have for BLOBs, so it's up to using SQL.

If you want a reason for that omission, it's partly due to the fact that RAW is not a commonly used data type in Oracle Database.

Related: if you're talking about LONG RAW
We (Oracle) recommend you stop using it, and instead convert them to BLOBs.

> The LONG RAW datatype is provided for backward compatibility with
>   existing applications. For new applications, use the BLOB and BFILE
>   datatypes for large amounts of binary data. Oracle also recommends
>   that you convert existing LONG RAW columns to LOB columns. LOB columns
>   are subject to far fewer restrictions than LONG columns. Further, LOB
>   functionality is enhanced in every release, whereas LONG RAW
>   functionality has been static for several releases.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. But I think raw data type is useful and edit the value can be done like varchar2 type so I think it is simple to develop. Is there any chance to develop it in the future?

Comment: @MostafaVatanpour no chance, see my amended answer.

Comment: I know LONG RAW datatype is depricated but not raw datatype.

Comment: since you didn't provide the table definition, i wasn't sure. but also, the usage of RAW in customers I interact with, is VERY little. It's not a priority, today.

Comment: I changed my question. Thank you for your responses.